# Ansible is not working for Facts and Banners modules in Aruba AOS-CX

Tags: ansible

When I work with Ansible aoscx_command module Everything works fine, but when I use other modules of Aruba AOS-CX like banner and facts it doesn't work.

Here in output you can see that task 1 works perfectly, but problem arise in second task.

Also I try to use [this](https://community.arubanetworks.com/discussion/ansible-ansiblemodule-utilsconnectionconnectionerror-method-not-found?ReturnUrl=%2Fcommunity-home%2Fdigestviewer%3FReturnUrl%3D%252Fcommunity-home%252Fdigestviewer%253FMessageKey%253D19b909d6-5bf5-4ef6-b721-376c8bbf53d4%2526CommunityKey%253D867d34a4-1e6a-4b9a-9349-df7b4c84b3cb%2526ReturnUrl%253D%25252Fcommunity-home%25252Fdigestviewer%25253FMessageKey%25253Da7e34f25-ccd4-4603-ad9f-8a49a86090d0%252526CommunityKey%25253D867d34a4-1e6a-4b9a-9349-df7b4c84b3cb)
, But still it does not resolve my problem.

Thank you :)

## **playbook.yml**

```
- hosts: all
  collections:
    - arubanetworks.aoscx
  tasks:
    - name: Execute show vlan on the switch and register
      aoscx_command:
        commands: ['show vlan']
      register: show_vlan_output
 
    - name: >
        Retrieve all information from the device and save into a variable
        "facts_output".
      aoscx_facts:
      register: facts_output
```

## **hosts.yml**

```
all:
  hosts:
    cxos1:
      ansible_host: 10.10.0.31
      ansible_user: admin
      ansible_password: admin
      ansible_network_os: arubanetworks.aoscx.aoscx
      ansible_connection: arubanetworks.aoscx.aoscx  # REST API via pyaoscx connection method
      ansible_aoscx_validate_certs: False
      ansible_aoscx_use_proxy: False
      ansible_acx_no_proxy: True
```

## **Detailed Output**

```
root@ansible:/etc/ansible/arubalab1# ansible-playbook file1.yml -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.10.8
  config file = /etc/ansible/arubalab1/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0]
Using /etc/ansible/arubalab1/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/arubalab1/hosts.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/arubalab1/hosts.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/arubalab1/hosts.yml inventory source with yaml plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: file1.yml *****************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in file1.yml

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/arubalab1/file1.yml:1
redirecting (type: connection) ansible.builtin.network_cli to ansible.netcommon.network_cli
[WARNING]: ansible-pylibssh not installed, falling back to paramiko
<10.10.0.31> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011371.9972951-13360-95548483069557 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1678011371.9972951-13360-95548483069557="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011371.9972951-13360-95548483069557 `" ) && sleep 0'
<cxos1> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.9'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.8'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.7'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.6'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.5'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python2.7'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python2.6'"'"'; command -v '"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'; command -v '"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/setup.py
<10.10.0.31> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/tmplpdaccdz TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011371.9972951-13360-95548483069557/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011371.9972951-13360-95548483069557/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011371.9972951-13360-95548483069557/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011371.9972951-13360-95548483069557/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011371.9972951-13360-95548483069557/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [cxos1]
META: ran handlers

TASK [Execute show vlan on the switch and register] *********************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/arubalab1/file1.yml:7
redirecting (type: connection) ansible.builtin.network_cli to ansible.netcommon.network_cli
<10.10.0.31> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011373.9149337-13471-31150715387427 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1678011373.9149337-13471-31150715387427="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011373.9149337-13471-31150715387427 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/arubanetworks/aoscx/plugins/modules/aoscx_command.py
<10.10.0.31> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/tmpqy_j0708 TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011373.9149337-13471-31150715387427/AnsiballZ_aoscx_command.py
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011373.9149337-13471-31150715387427/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011373.9149337-13471-31150715387427/AnsiballZ_aoscx_command.py && sleep 0'
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011373.9149337-13471-31150715387427/AnsiballZ_aoscx_command.py && sleep 0'
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011373.9149337-13471-31150715387427/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [cxos1] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "commands": [
                "show vlan"
            ],
            "interval": 1,
            "match": "all",
            "output_file": null,
            "output_file_format": "json",
            "provider": null,
            "retries": 10,
            "wait_for": null
        }
    },
    "stdout": [
        "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nVLAN  Name                              Status  Reason                  Type        Interfaces                    \n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n1     DEFAULT_VLAN_1                    down    no_member_port          default"
    ],
    "stdout_lines": [
        [
            "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "VLAN  Name                              Status  Reason                  Type        Interfaces                    ",
            "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "1     DEFAULT_VLAN_1                    down    no_member_port          default"
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [Retrieve all information from the device and save into a variable "facts_output".] ********************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/arubalab1/file1.yml:12
redirecting (type: connection) ansible.builtin.network_cli to ansible.netcommon.network_cli
<10.10.0.31> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/arubanetworks/aoscx/plugins/modules/aoscx_facts.py
<10.10.0.31> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/tmph88u1w6k TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/AnsiballZ_aoscx_facts.py
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/AnsiballZ_aoscx_facts.py && sleep 0'
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/AnsiballZ_aoscx_facts.py && sleep 0'
<10.10.0.31> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/AnsiballZ_aoscx_facts.py", line 102, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/AnsiballZ_aoscx_facts.py", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/AnsiballZ_aoscx_facts.py", line 40, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.arubanetworks.aoscx.plugins.modules.aoscx_facts', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 224, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload_kekff_g7/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload.zip/ansible_collections/arubanetworks/aoscx/plugins/modules/aoscx_facts.py", line 436, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload_kekff_g7/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload.zip/ansible_collections/arubanetworks/aoscx/plugins/modules/aoscx_facts.py", line 270, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload_kekff_g7/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload.zip/ansible_collections/arubanetworks/aoscx/plugins/module_utils/aoscx_pyaoscx.py", line 82, in get_pyaoscx_session
  File "/tmp/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload_kekff_g7/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload.zip/ansible_collections/arubanetworks/aoscx/plugins/module_utils/aoscx_pyaoscx.py", line 47, in __init__
  File "/tmp/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload_kekff_g7/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py", line 195, in __rpc__
ansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: Method not found
fatal: [cxos1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/AnsiballZ_aoscx_facts.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/AnsiballZ_aoscx_facts.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1335037ckzoks/ansible-tmp-1678011381.2261038-13550-24650846479639/AnsiballZ_aoscx_facts.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.arubanetworks.aoscx.plugins.modules.aoscx_facts', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 224, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 86, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload_kekff_g7/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload.zip/ansible_collections/arubanetworks/aoscx/plugins/modules/aoscx_facts.py\", line 436, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload_kekff_g7/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload.zip/ansible_collections/arubanetworks/aoscx/plugins/modules/aoscx_facts.py\", line 270, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload_kekff_g7/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload.zip/ansible_collections/arubanetworks/aoscx/plugins/module_utils/aoscx_pyaoscx.py\", line 82, in get_pyaoscx_session\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload_kekff_g7/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload.zip/ansible_collections/arubanetworks/aoscx/plugins/module_utils/aoscx_pyaoscx.py\", line 47, in __init__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload_kekff_g7/ansible_aoscx_facts_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py\", line 195, in __rpc__\nansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: Method not found\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************
cxos1                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: What Ansible version is used? where the [requirements](https://developer.arubanetworks.com/aruba-aoscx/docs/getting-started-with-ansible-and-aos-cx#section-installing-the-aruba-aos-cx-collection) for the Aruba collection installed? There is a an [issue](https://github.com/aruba/aoscx-ansible-collection/issues/37) reported, with similar outcomes, that was caused by not having the requirements properly set.

Comment: It works now :) I have removed **ansible_connection: network_cli** from all locations. In some modules it is required and in some it is not.